What does "contradictions trivialize truth" mean?
I hope there's no regulations against posting a series of consecutive questions.
In the past decade or so I've read around 3-4 books on logic; they were 101's (introductory books) so more about application than theory.
Several methods of argumentation were taught as special, 1) the conditional proof and 2) reductio ad absurdum. A reductio argument has as its conclusion a contradiction which then falsifies one/some/all of the premises(?).
On the matter of contradictions (p ∧ ¬p), I did some reading, mostly from Wikipedia, and the claim is "contradictions trivialize truth". I know of trivialism per which all statements are true and I can see how we get there via ex contradictione sequitur quodlibet but I have an issue.
What does it mean exactly, to trivialize truth?
My own take on this is that it is negation that is being trivialized in the sense that it's an empty operator, "doesn't do anything at all" as p is true AND also ¬p is true.

Everything becomes true, so truth becomes a trivial notion.

Contradictions falsify the conjunction of the premises, not any one or some in particular. "Trivializing truth" means that every sentence is deduced to be both true and false. Hence the system with a contradiction cannot play the usual discriminating role of classifying sentences into two disjoint groups, true and false ones.

It is basically a wring saying: what is true is true and what is false is false. A system that proves a contradiction will prove everything, both true and false claims. Thus, what is "trivial" is the system that fails wrt its basic purpose: to prove/discover truth.

@NaïmFavier can replace the word "trivial" with a phrase in your answer? I can imagine a world where everything is true (mayhaps the union of all possible worlds). That isn't trivial, right?

@Conifold, I tried that and though it doesn't answer my question, cogito it's circular: contradictions are no good because contradictions are no good.

@MauroALLEGRANZA read my answer to Conifold

"Trivial" as in "not interesting" or "too simple to be worth talking about". This is standard usage in mathematics, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triviality_(mathematics)

@NaïmFavier, is everything is true really not interesting? Perhaps the issue is an idiosyncratic one (pertaining to me alone). Thank you for the math example, I kinda sorta get how trivial it is to say that a^n + b^n = c^n is true for n = 0.

You cannot imagine a world where everything is true. How would you imagine that you are and are not in such a world? Possible worlds are, on one interpretation, maximally consistent sets of sentences, exactly those that can be "imagined" at the same time. Their union will not be so imaginable, that is what discrimination into true and false is for.

@Conifold, suppose there are 2 propositions p and q. A truth table will demonstrate that p is true in at least one world and q is true in at least one world. The union of these 2 worlds would have both p and q being true, albeit in different worlds, right? Non liquet

Stringing together propositions on paper or in the head does not guarantee that the result is imaginable or makes any sense. Paper can suffer anything. Truth tables are of no help when it comes to imagining a world. You have to imagine a room where you are and are not. At the same time. Try it. This is why people puzzle over Schrödinger's cat, although it is not quite the same.

@Conifold, ok but how exactly does a contradiction trivialize truth? I know the justification for why contradictions are unacceptable, viz. the principle of explosion, which is that everything becomes true. What if everything is true? Non liquet,

If everything is true then you are and are not there. Such worlds are not sensible and hence useless for the purposes of hypothetical world-building. And world-building is a prerequisite for modeling something and then acting on the results. A model that tells you both to move and to stay put does not tell you anything actionable and is worthless as a model.

@Conifold that's the circularity I was referring to: a contradiction is unacceptable because it leads to contradictions. How is that a good justification? Please write an answer, if that's not too much trouble.

No, it is unacceptable because it makes applying models to reality and action impossible, and that is their primary purpose. There is no circularity there. If we simply played games with symbols contradictions would be just fine.

@Conifold but models must reflect reality and if reality is such that everything is true ...

"True" does not apply to reality, only to descriptions of it, so "reality is such that..." is a category error. And one has to live and act in it, hence discriminate between doing and not doing. Descriptions that make everything true fail at that task.

@Conifold, please write an answer.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Several direct, technical explications can be the given for the mentioned phrase, particularly, within the context of paraconsistent systems of logic, because the fundamental motivation of those systems is to allow a contradiction to hold, that is, both P and ¬P hold for some proposition P, but without "trivialising truth" (i.e., all propositions become true).
I shall bring forward an indirect, conceptual context to see the phrase under another, broader light. Trivialising truth, whether by contradiction or by some other notion, can be regarded as an extreme form of relativism. A concise definition of this generic position is offered in Emrys Westacott's IEP article on relativism as

Although there are many different kinds of relativism, they all have
two features in common.
(1) They all assert that one thing (e.g. moral values, beauty,
knowledge, taste, or meaning) is relative to some particular framework
or standpoint (e.g. the individual subject, a culture, an era, a
language, or a conceptual scheme).
(2) They all deny that any standpoint is uniquely privileged over all
others.

So, for example, suppose a social norm may allow, and even, encourage a behaviour in one society, while an antagonistic norm of another society may reject and strongly discourage such a behaviour. The relativist viewpoint, taken typically, tend to uphold that both attitudes should be accepted right, for each case has its own validating conditions, thus, render any moral evaluation insignificant.
Allowing contradictions in a logical system can be seen as an abstractive (hence, converting the sides to polar opposites) reflection of a relativist position in this sense: P is true by its truth conditions, and ¬P is also true by its own truth conditions. Thus, the notion truth is deflated to a trivial status with no essentially discriminating power; there remains nothing of interest to inspect and assess whether some assertion is true or false.

Thank you for your kind words. It can be phrased as you say. When the distinction is trivialised, the notion becomes bereft of its definitive element and it is trivialised, too.

Superb answer. Truth and falsity are antithetical dualistic concepts that help us as @Conifold stated to separate reality from illusion. If contradictions are allowed we end up losing that discriminatory power, undermining as it were the very purpose of truth (includes falsum). Good that you brought up relativism. From a Jain anekantavada (no one-sidedness) POV, claims are always prefixed with syad (to remind us that the claim is (only) a perspective.

What if the truth is that everything is true. In this case are we still trivializing the truth? The model (trivialism) is accurately applicable to reality then, si? Also can you opine on my take that it is negation that's being trivialized, it serves no purpose?

Thank you for your appreciation. Your last question opens up many ramifications; it may be appropriate to move back and forth between premisses and consequences to accurately stabilise thought in such cases. For an instance, we can consider that of Leibniz's thesis of best of all possible worlds. From a critic's viewpoint, yes, Leibniz's optimism trivialises the truth. The questions on triviality arise not from that negation fails in its function (it fulfils its function), but from deductive and semantic principles adopted. You may wish to see the views on paraconsistency and dialethism.

I see there are many meanings of "trivial(ize)" and in your answer you zeroed in on one specific definition (losing the valuable distinction true vs. false). Can you expand/elaborate on that? We can talk about Herr Leibniz and his effect on alethia as a different question if you deem it worth your time. It may be critical to a more complete understanding of verum vis-à-vis contradictione. As for Brazilian logic, do you have a download link to a simple book on it?

By "Brazilian logic," I understand a version of relevant (a.k.a. relevance) logic. I can recommend Stephen Read's Relevant Logic: A Philosophical Examination of Inference. Though Read develops his version, the book offers philosophical considerations and freely downloadable. I think progressing with focused questions would be more helpful, as witnessed, the community here does not remain unconcerned with such issues.

It trivializes truth because anything follows from the assumption, p and not p, in a trivial way.
So, now the proof of any statement becomes a trivial proof, no matter how complicated the statement is. Also, that the statement can be deduced at all is also trivial, since all statements can be deduced.
Assume p and ¬p, we prove q
Proof:
Assume p
Assume ¬p
We then have ( the details on how, depend on the exact specifications of the logic we are working in)
p → (¬q → p) This form is often just taken as an axiom.
by Modus Ponens
¬q → p
by Modus Tollens
¬¬q
by double negation syllogism
q
Remark: I would say that trivial here, refers to the fact that the result follows from a simple argument- which holds regardless of the complexity of q.
It also refers to how, the question of "is there a proof of q"- is trivially answered in the affirmative.
It's not really that "truth" is trivialized. It is that proofs are trivialized.
To say that truth is trivialized, we need to add the further assumption that things we are able to prove, are true.

The wording is quite clear. Although I agree with your, proving (anything) is a trivial exercise, it's truth that's trivialized. Perhaps the point is dualistic in nature, having to do with the contradistinction true vs. false. It's non liquet
